# Disable scp for all IP, but allow it for given ones

Tags: ssh, scp

There is a server running sshd. 
We have root permission on it.

**Question**: How can we disable SCP on it, BUT: allow a given IP to SCP (copy to it, etc.)

Maybe rename the SCP binary and have a "Match User root" entry with the correct scp path or how?

UPDATE: all access should be allowed, only scp need to be blocked*. 
*but whitelist given IP's for scp

Comment: Do other ISPs need to be able to access that machine as well? And if so, in what way?

Comment: I updated the question, hope it clarifies it.

Comment: So ssh should be allowed for all ISPs, for example?

Comment: You cannot prevent users from transfering files by disabling scp.  There's many other loopholes like tar, rsync, shar, etc.

Comment: that is not the problem, of course anybody can convert anything to base64 and CTRL+C/CTRL+V it to the ssh console, then convert bas64 to the original data...

Comment: Blocking only SCP seems like a lot of effort for no benefit. If the user can still run SFTP or has access to the unix command line, there are lots of other ways to transfer files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys to restrict what the users can do;

```
command="/noscp.sh" ssh-dss blablabla== whatever@user.email
```

;

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" =~ scp* -a ! "$SSH_CLIENT" =~ 10.10.10.10* ]] ; then
   echo "Rejected" >&2
   echo "$(date) fail $SSH_CLIENT $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" >> noscp.log
   exit 1
else
   $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
fi
exit
```

Although this is doable it would be best if you told us your goal as it's pointless to block scp when files can be copied directly through ssh, etc. It generally makes more sense to simply limit functionality by user ssh key not user source IP.

Comment: the answer looks good, but I am still waiting, maybe others know another way, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Match Address *,!10.10.10.10/32
        ForceCommand /bin/bash
```

This forces `/bin/bash` on all addresses except `10.10.10.10/32` effectively not permitting `scp`

From `man sshd_config`

> **Match**
>
> Introduces a conditional block.  If all of the criteria on the Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines
> override those set in the global section of the config file, until
> either another Match line or the end of the file.  If a keyword appears in multiple Match blocks that are satisfied, only the
> first instance of the keyword is applied.
>
> The arguments to Match are one or more criteria-pattern pairs or the single token All which matches all criteria.  The
> available criteria are **User, Group, Host, LocalAddress, LocalPort,**
> **RDomain, and Address** (with RDomain representing the rdomain(4) on which the connection was received).
>
> The match patterns may consist of single entries or comma-separated lists and may use the wildcard and negation operators
> described in the PATTERNS section of ssh_config(5).
>
> The patterns in an Address criteria may additionally contain addresses to match in CIDR address/masklen format, such as
> 192.0.2.0/24 or 2001:db8::/32.  Note that the mask length provided must
> be consistent with the address - it is an error to specify a mask length that is too long for the address or one with
> bits set in this host portion of the address.  For example,
> 192.0.2.0/33 and 192.0.2.0/8, respectively.
>
> Only a subset of keywords may be used on the lines following a Match keyword.  Available keywords are **AcceptEnv, AllowAgentForwarding, AllowGroups, AllowStreamLocalForwarding, AllowTcpForwarding, AllowUsers, AuthenticationMethods, AuthorizedKeysCommand, AuthorizedKeysCommandUser, AuthorizedKeysFile, AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand, AuthorizedPrincipalsCommandUser, AuthorizedPrincipalsFile, Banner, ChrootDirectory, ClientAliveCountMax, ClientAliveInterval, DenyGroups, DenyUsers, ForceCommand, GatewayPorts, GSSAPIAuthentication, HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes, HostbasedAuthentication, HostbasedUsesNameFromPacketOnly, Include, IPQoS, KbdInteractiveAuthentication, KerberosAuthentication, LogLevel, MaxAuthTries, MaxSessions, PasswordAuthentication, PermitEmptyPasswords, PermitListen, PermitOpen, PermitRootLogin, PermitTTY, PermitTunnel, PermitUserRC, PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes, PubkeyAuthentication, RekeyLimit, RevokedKeys, RDomain, SetEnv, StreamLocalBindMask, StreamLocalBindUnlink, TrustedUserCAKeys, X11DisplayOffset, X11Forwarding and X11UseLocalhost**.

Comment: Won't that also prevent the user from running other commands, like `ssh user@host uptime`?

Comment: Also it's totally pointless to preven the user from running scp *directly* (they could still do it *indirectly* via the `-S` option) while allowing her to use a full shell.

Comment: @UncleBilly I wanted the first point as well, so as to prevent users from getting files like `ssh user@host "cat /remote/path/to/file" > /local/path/to/file`, but I don't understand your second point of `-S` option. Could you please provide an example

Comment: **1.** you don't prevent it at all; (after directing some choice words at you and your loved ones ;-)) the user will succeed with `echo cat /remote/path | ssh user@host > /local/path`. **2.** `scp -S ./script local/path user@host:remote/path` where `./script` is something like `a=$*; h=${a% scp *}; t=${a#* scp }; { echo scp $t; cat; } | ssh $h` (yeah, that script could be made a lot more robust ;-)).